# Query for statistics on two columns in MySQL database

Tags: mysql, sql, statistics, analytics

I am looking to find statistics on two columns in a MySQL database. For a single column, I am using the following query....

```
SELECT fname, count(fname) as nameCount, count(fname) / 
(SELECT count(fname) FROM user_detail)*100 as percent 
FROM user_detail GROUP BY fname order by percent desc;
```

Which is working quite well, for instance, the above variable is 'fname' for first name, it returns the first name, the count of identical first names, and the percentage that first name represents in the database.

My next step is to compare first names to states, for instance, I want to see how many people have the first name 'Jeffrey' in the state 'Florida' but I am not sure how to write that query, any thoughts, ideas, or suggestions is greatly appreciated.

Comment: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user_detail WHERE fname = 'Jeffrey' and state = 'Florida'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query will give you counts by state but the percentages will be calculated for the whole table.

```
SELECT fname, count(fname) as nameCount, count(fname) / 
    (SELECT count(fname) FROM user_detail)*100 as percent 
FROM user_detail GROUP BY fname, state order by percent desc;
```

For percentages by state try this

```
SELECT fname, count(fname) as nameCount, count(fname) / 
    (SELECT count(fname) FROM user_detail as u WHERE u.state = d.satte)*100 as percent 
FROM user_detail as d GROUP BY fname, state order by percent desc;
```